# how to implement custom tailwind animation in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In svelte i want to create this animation, but how ?

This class should in added or remvoed from div depend on the state of animation.

```
<!--
Dropdown menu, show/hide based on menu state.

Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
    From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    
Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
    From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
-->
```

When isUserMenuOpen boolean flag is toggle

```
{#if isUserMenuOpen}
    <div transition:fade>
        <UserDropMenu />
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Just use CSS or the Svelte transition system directly. There is probably no value in trying to use Tailwind for that.

Answer (score 1):

[To create a custom animation in tailwind you extend the tailwind config file.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#customizing-your-theme)

Something like:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        fade-in: {
          from: { opacity: 0%; scale: 95%; },
          to: { opacity: 100%; scale: 100%; },
        },
        fade-out: {
          from: { opacity: 100%; scale: 100%; },
          to: { opacity: 0%; scale: 95%; },
        }
      },
      animation: {
        'animation-in': '1s ease-out 0 fade-in',
        'animation-out': '0.75s ease-in 0 fade-out',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for showing it in svelte you can do something like:

```
<script>
    let show = false;
    let hide = false;
</script>

{#if show}
<h1 class:animation-in={show && !hide}
    class:animation-out={hide}
    on:animationend={() => {if(hide) {show = false; hide = false;}}}>
    Hello
</h1>
{/if}

<button on:click={() => show = true}>
    show
</button>

<button on:click={() => hide = true}>
    hide
</button>
```

There might be better ways to manage this state, but I think this should work unless I messed up the tailwind config part (order of elements in the animation is probably wrong and from and to keywords in keyframes might not work instead of 0%, 100%).